# uploading Docker image GCP once every N uploads?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

In java, everything is packaged already so nicely that I really don't need to upload a DockerImage each and every deploy.  In fact, I really only want to upload it when I change it.  Is there a way to either

- Deploy the container once and re-use OR
- Upload my package and build and deploy docker in the cloud so that our deploys are much much faster?

I am starting to wonder if I deploy a docker image that can build a docker image or something and run the google cloud commands in the cloud.

Any thoughts?

(the real issue is jumping from alpine jdk8 to jdk10+ images really really slowed the upload time since the images are so large).

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about your deployments? Are them to Cloud Run, App Engine or another tool?

Comment: cloud run.  There was a gcloud builder too but that seems to give no status/feedback on how long it's taking which is annoying.

Comment: I did a bit of research, and there doesn't seem to be a way to not upload the image during the deploy. This is most likely due to the way in which Cloud run creates the containers